# Can't resolve Method 'button clicked ( android.view.View) '

Tags: android

I am trying to set up an On click listener using android studio and i keep get the following error message "Can't resolve Method  'button clicked ( android.view.View) " what does this mean and how do i solve this problem  ?

```
package com.example.curtis.memegenerator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;    

button.setOnClickListener(
  new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
              **buttonClicked(v);**- error is here
         }
  }
};
```

Comment: Paste your logcat error.

Comment: Please provide associated code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @All- please let me know if you require more code

Comment: Check my answer and add full code if something wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You missed `)`.
2. Do you set this listener in your class or in method? This should be added in method...
3. If you added it properly, does `buttonClicked(View v)` is declarated in the same class?
4. Fixed code:

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener(
               new View.OnClickListener(){
                   public void onClick(View v){
                       buttonClicked(v);
                   }
               });
   ```

Comment: Which solution solved your problem? Adding missing `)` or adding listener in method? Anyway, when problem is solved, mark it as answered by clicking tick near answer.